# How do I reuse Rspec let expressions across spec files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'd like to dry up some of my spec files that share some of the same `let` expressions by shoving them into a module (or by doing something else you might suggest). When I do that I'm getting an error when I run the spec:

> undefined method `let' for SpecShared:Module (NoMethodError)

I'm requiring the module in rails_helper.rb

I'm requiring rails_helper.rb in my module

It seems like the module is either not requiring rails_helper.rb properly, or needs to require something else. What else/instead would I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will want to create a shared context:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/example-groups/shared-context